# Magento 2: wrong url causing css problems

Tags: magento2, installation, apache, centos

I'm running centos 7, mysql and apache vps. Magento web wizard setup was located at

`example.com/magento`

The installer asked me where I want to install magento, I said `example.com`

The installation went smoothly without any errors. However when that was done, it got installed in `example.com/magento`, I mean if you want to go to the homepage you go there.

Furthermore, the homepage doesn't load correctly, it loads as shown in [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy)

Why am I asking the question instead of following the highest voted answer there?

1. The other question doesn't address how to fix the URL issue,magento installed itself in the wrong directory.
2. The other question say to `chmod 777 -R magento/`. Are you serious? I just want to double check this 777? Isn't that a bit insecure? Back in my days, this was insanity, but I'm old so what do I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the URL to point to the subfolder, you can either modify the base URLs in the database as I assume you can't access the backend.

You want to update in the `core_config_data` table both `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to point to the base of the magento site.

Then reindex and clear the site cache

---

With setting permissions, Magento has seemed to have rewritten their permission spec recently.

I have always set 770 on folders and 660 on files as per Magento's (now old) spec
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/legacy-file-system-perms.html

But as per Magento's new Spec, they seem to recommend 775 for folders and 664 for files
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: The base_url is set correctly in the database in both fields you specified, it's set to example.com, however I can only access it from example.com/magento, I don't want that

Comment: I see, 2 ways to solve this,
1) Move the files on the server up a level so they sit outside the Magento folder
2) Or modify your Nginx / Apache doc root to point within your Magento folder

Comment: Alright, that solves the url, now if I go to admin url, I get 404 page not found, I deleted the cache. Haven't fixed permissions yet. What's the next step

Comment: That sounds like an URL rewrite issue to me, when you moved the files did you make sure to remove the hidden files too? So .htaccess etc. If you did, I would recommend making sure apache rewrites are enabled. If it is I  would recommend going over the Magento 2 docs for after the setup process https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/verify.html

Comment: Issue solved I used this htaccess https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112109/39008 thanks for your time, you are awesome, I wish you all the best this life has to give.